# Fixed Array Size In C query

Tags: c

Sorry for the trouble.
I've the following array list that is initialized as size 1. However i can do a scanf and loop through list[0] to list[4] without having any problem in visual studio 2010.

Isn't there supposed to have an error here?

```
void main()
{   
    int i=0,menu_choice=0;
    int size;
    int list[1]; //array initialized with size 1
    do{ 
        printMenu();
        printf("Enter Your Choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&menu_choice);
        switch(menu_choice){
        case 1:
            printf("\n");
            printf("Enter array size: ");
            scanf("%d",&size);
            printf("Enter %d numbers: ",size);
            for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&list[i]);
            }   
            for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                printf("%d",list[i]);
            }
            break;

        default :
            printf("Please select the right choice \n");
            break;
        }

    }
    while(menu_choice!=8);


}
```

Comment: C allows you to shoot yourself in the foot in many nice ways, like writing beyond the limits of an array. It will however lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Move `int list[1];` to be the first line in `main` and see how things change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C doesn't do implicit array bounds checking like your friendly neighborhood Java does.

C will gladly let a program run off the ends of an array (or any allocated memory) when the programmer isn't careful.  This leads to undefined behavior (oftentimes a memory segmentation or violation fault) and is a common attack vector for hackers ([buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)).

The same goes for C++ too.

Comment: Thanks bro. What if i were to put a   "list[size];" directly after the "printf("Enter array size: ");" statement? 

Will c re-initialize the array with the right size?  Or the only way is to use malloc?

Comment: @ericlee That depends on your compiler.  C99 does allow that, but not all compilers implement Variable Length Arrays (VLAs), which is the name of that feature. MS Visual Studio notably does not allow VLAs AFAIK.

Comment: @jschultz410 VLAs cannot be resized

Comment: @ericlee you could do the input first, and then write `int list[size];` , and then do the rest of your logic.  Of course, `malloc` is another option.

Comment: @MattMcNabb  does it mean that
i'll keep the   int list[1]; and than i will re-initialize it again directly after the "printf("Enter array size: ");" statement? by having list[size];?

Comment: @ericlee no, you cannot "reinitialize" things in C. `list[size];` means to access the `size`-th numbered element of `list`.

Comment: @ericlee: Sorry if I was a bit imprecise.  I thought you meant if you move the declaration of list to be directly after the `scanf("%d",&size);` and made it be "int list[size];"  If you do this though, `list` will only be accessible within the `switch` statement due to scoping rules.  You also need to ensure that `size` is positive before you declare a VLA with it (not sure if 0 is valid -- probably not).  Regardless, Visual Studio doesn't support VLAs.

Comment: Also, while C99 mandated VLAs, C11 made VLAs optional, so your code may be less portable.